# How to process 80MB+ xlsx to database MySQL with PHPExcel?

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I need to insert all the data in an Excel file (.xlsx) to my database. I have tried all the available methods, such as caching, make it read chunk by chunk but nothing seems to work at all. Has anyone tried to do this with a big file size before? My spreadsheet has about 32 columns and about 700,000 rows of records.

The file is already uploaded in the server. And I want to write a cron job to actually read the excel file and insert the data to the database. I chunk it to read each time 5000, 3000 or even 10 records only, but none worked. What happens is it will return this error:

> simplexml_load_string(): Memory allocation failed: growing buffer.

I did try with CSV file type and manage to get the thing run at 4000k records each time but will take about five minutes each time to process, but any higher will fail too. And get the same error. But the requirement need it in .xlsx file types, so I need to stick with that.

Comment: In what way is the file being provided to the application? Direct file reference? Upload control? FTP/SSH/rsync/etc? Are you doing this in a web app or a console program? When you have tried the things you have tried, what happened? Did you run out memory or get an error? (Please edit the answers into your question, so it is substantially more detailed).

Comment: @halfer the file is already uploaded in the server, need to load the data to mysql using cron job

Comment: Great, an error message. This leads directly [to this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=simplexml_load_string%28%29%3A+Memory+allocation+failed%3A+growing+buffer), where you'll find some people who've already had the same problem. I should think at least one of those is a duplicate of this.

Comment: @halfer I checked out the link you shared, but none of them found solution to solve this.

Comment: Nevertheless, this is still a duplicate (I appreciate you don't have the reputation to comment on other posts, but I'm not sure creating a duplicate is the answer, especially if people were not able to solve it before anyway). Those links may not offer full solutions, but might they give you some new avenues for research?

Comment: How much memory do you actually have set for PHP to use in your php.ini file? If PHPExcel is failing even loading the file with simplexml_load_string() then nothing is going to work short of increasing your memory limit, because it can't even start to load the data

Comment: Did you ever get this to work... I believe my program can handle the task and would love an opportunity to prove it.  http://excel2mysql.net

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting it to CSV format using external tool, like `ssconvert` from `Gnumeric` package and then read CSV line by line with `fgetcsv` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue occurs because you are trying to read the contents of a whole XML file. Caching and reading chunk by chunk does not help because the library you are using needs to read the entire XML file at one point to determine the structure of the spreadsheet.
So for very large files, the XML file is so big that reading it consumes all the available memory. The only working option is to use streamers and optimize the reading.

This is still a pretty complex problem. For instance, to resolve the data in your sheet, you need to read the shared strings from one XML file and the structure of your sheet from another one. Because of the way shared strings are stored, you need to have those strings in memory when reading the sheet structure. If you have thousands of shared strings, that becomes a problem.

If you are interested, [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout) solves this problem. It is open-source so you can take a look at the code!